# Uploadifive: Show error/result from uploadifive.php at each queue element

Tags: jquery, uploadify

I'm using uploadifive (non-flash version of uploadify), for uploading with jquery and php

I'm looking for ways to treat what is being returned (echo'ed) from uploadifive.php, same way as errors/results are shown by jquery on each file queue element

```
 'onUploadComplete (or maybe onProgress)' : function(file, data) {
 // show the php result/error at the queue element
 }
```

As it is now, it says "Completed" for the file no matter what php returns

I'm thinking, I should fiddle around with the uploadifive.js file.. but where excactly and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just had the same problem and found that "**file.xhr.responseText**" will output the content echoed by the backend script.

Good Luck!

Comment: Yes, I discovered that too by investigating the script ;) Thanks

Comment: How exactly is this the correct solution? I'm encountering the same problem but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: This is solution with "file.xhr.responseText" and this definitively save my day - Thanks!  http://www.uploadify.com/forum/#/discussion/9139/custom-errors-dont-register-says-completed-instead-/p1

Answer (score 0):

You can access the data echoed in the script in the data variable…
Then you can handle it as you want :

For instance, if everything is ok I don't echo anything, but if something wrong happens (file too big, bad format …) I echo the message in my php script and then

```
'onUploadComplete': function (file, data) {
                    $('#uplodifive_errors').append('<div class="alert alert-error alert-dismissable">File "' + file['name'] + '" : ' + data + '</div>');
                },
```

I show it in a error div.